# Termination of the Bellman-Ford algorithm in asynchronous distributed model

Tags: algorithm, graph, distributed, distributed-computing, graph-algorithm

I'm looking for an algorithm to compute the BFS tree of a graph rooted in the leader processor `r` in the asynchronous distributed model.

The only requirement is `O(D)` time complexity, where `D` denotes the diameter of the graph (message complexity isn't relevant).

Currently, I'm using Bellman-Ford algorithm, but I don't know how to guarantee the global termination of this method in `O(D)` time. I was trying to use the convergecast technique, but with no success.

Is it possible to guarantee a termination of Bellman-Ford in `O(D)` time or is there any other algorithm for computing the BFS tree in `O(D)` time?

Comment: If you don't care about the message complexity, use a time-efficient synchronizer.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat My work is purely theoretical, so I don't want to use synchronizers. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: [Synchronizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronizer_%28algorithm%29)

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I read the paper about synchronizers. If I understood correctly, I can use the alpha synchronizer to simulate the execution of the Synchronized Flood algorithm to compute the BFS tree, next use a convergecast from leaves up to the root and finally, the root broadcasts the termination message. Is it a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, design a time-efficient algorithm for a synchronous system and compose it with Awerbuch's time-efficient Alpha synchronizer (1985), which simulates a synchronous system.